# ¿Cómo optimizar las imágenes que utilizo en mi app para evitar el sobrecargo de recursos?

Tags: android, imagen, android-imageview

Simplemente al abrir la app y mostrarse el 'Splash' el dispositivo se sobrecarga y las transiciones no fluyen correctamente (esto ocurre en todas las pantallas de mi app). En el archivo del 'Splash' XML sólo utilizo 3 objetos: un contenedor y dos imágenes. Y en la clase lo único que hace es mostrar esas dos imágenes con animaciones que demoran más o menos 1 segundo por cada imagen, y luego pasa al menú principal.

Archivo XML 'Splash'

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/info_fondo">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenNombreApp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_blanco"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imagen" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenNombreApp2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nombre_app_imagen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imagen" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Clase 'Splash'

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView logoImagen, logoNombre;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    logoNombre = findViewById(R.id.imagenNombreApp2);
    logoNombre.setAlpha(0f);
    logoImagen = findViewById(R.id.imagenNombreApp);
    logoImagen.setAlpha(0f);
    logoImagen.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(800)
            .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    logoNombre.animate()
                            .alpha(1f)
                            .setDuration(800)
                            .setListener(null);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, HomeMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 2200);

}
```

}

Utilizo algo llamado 'Perfil de aceleración de GPU' para verificar en dónde está la falla. Lo que hace es mostrarme unas barras que representan procesos ([les dejo la documentación](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering?hl=es-419#profile_rendering)). En fin, cuando eliminé al menos la imagen de fondo, el cambio fue notable y al eliminar uno de los dos ImageView, mejoró aún más.

Así que mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo optimizar las imágenes o qué imágenes debo utilizar para no sobrecargar los dispositivos? Y adicional ¿De qué tamaño deben ser las imágenes para utilizarlas como fondo en un layout?
Debo añadir que la aplicación está llena de imágenes para hacerla más llamativa (iconos, fondos, imágenes representativas, etc)

Comment: Yo suelo optimizarlas antes de su procesamiento en código con programas de edición gráfica, como photoshop. Por ejemplo, ese width y height que has puesto, es el que aplico directamente en el tamaño de la imagen con photoshop antes de subirla a los recursos de la app. También es buena idea reducir un poco la calidad (en el móvil no necesitas mostrar una sábana) y para eso utilizo páginas como webresizer.com y similares.

Comment: @Mimmetico gracias por responder. Al principio yo usaba imágenes más pequeñas y no le asignaba ni un width ni un height específicos, pero vi que se veían horribles, borrosas. Por eso algunas como los íconos que uso para el menú las tengo en 256px. Y el fondo, pues uso uno de tamaño 1080x1920. Debo confesar que estoy obsesionado con la nitidez de las imágenes, no estoy bien si no se ven bien. He tratado de reducir lo más que puedo sin afectar su nitidez. Pero la verdad no puedo creer que no soporte 5 iconos de 128px o 256px.

Comment: @Mimmetico leí que es bueno utilizar Picasso, así que lo implementé sólo en mi 
pantalla de Splash, pero no funciona con un layout. Sabes cómo puedo optimizar la imagen del fondo?